# Multer handle error, problem with typescript types

Tags: typescript, express, multer

I have the following code:

```
import multer from "multer";
const upload = multer().single('file');
router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, async (err: any) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err.toString())
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).send(await addMedia(req.file.filename))
        }
    })
});
```

I am trying to determine the type, so I want to replace `any` by an appropriate Error type. When I try to replace it with `MulterError`, I get following error :

> Argument of type '(err: MulterError) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextFunction'. Types of parameters 'err' and 'deferToNext' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MulterError'.

`unknown` does not work due to the `.toString()`. `string` does work, but it is definitely not the correct type, as logging it shows me that I have a `MulterError`.

I don't completely understand what the 3rd parameter of the `upload` function is either - so that may be my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handled error

```
const storage: multer.StorageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (_req, _file, callback) => {
        const path = `./uploads/`;
        // creates folder if not exist
        fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true });
        callback(null, path);
    },
    filename: (_req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    }
});

const fileLimit = {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10 // limits the file size to 10MB
};
const fileFilter = (
    _req: Request,
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    callback: FileFilterCallback
) => {
    // return error if the file type is not image
    if (!file || file.mimetype.split('/')[0] != 'image') {
        return callback(new Error('Only images allowed'));
    }
    callback(null, true);
};

const upload: multer.Multer = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: fileLimit,
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});

const galleryUpload = upload.single('galleryImage');
// Upload gallery image
router.post('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    galleryUpload(req, res, (err: unknown) => {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
            return res.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
        } else if (err instanceof Error) {
            // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
            return res.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
        }
        return res.status(200).send({ message: 'Image uploaded successfully' });
    });
});
```